# how to solve react bootstrap css conflict with custom css

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using **ReactJS** and i am facing an issue where as soon as i add `react-boostrap` CDN in the `public/index.html` **react** file or add this link `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';` to `index.js`, Boostrap automatically disable the use of all the css i have built for the web application.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
// REACT-BOOTSTRAP
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint...
reportWebVitals();
```

I tried to fix it in `index.js` or any page i want to use `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'` by importing that after `import './index.css';` or any custom css but it does not seem to solve the conflict, is there a solution out there that i am not aware of?

Comment: You should import your custom CSS *after* importing the bootstrap CSS. Then check in the dev tools in your browser if your custom CSS is still included and if it is overwritten by the bootstrap styles. If that is the case, you need a [higher specificity](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp) in your CSS

Comment: @Taxel i will check the browser, but i also tried that option....what happened is my custom css did not fully work, weird right? only a part of it, i would say 50% of it on each page work and some part of the page do not

Comment: Don't use the package. Try to use original bootstrap with react. For more: https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-bootstrap-with-react-a354715d1121/ @feldobadix